# Substitute a variable in regexp.MatchString method

Tags: go

I have a golang script that needs to create and look for a particular regex. The string to look for id defined as a constant.

```
const nameRegex = "service-route"
```

I can use this variable in some places.

```
rb := &compute.Route{
        Name:           fmt.Sprintf("%s-%s", nameRegex, generateCode(host))
```

I would like to use the same string to find aswell.

Basically I have something like

```
matched, _ := regexp.MatchString("^service-route-.*", route.Name)
    if matched {
```

Doing something like

```
matched, _ := regexp.MatchString("^%s-.*" , nameRegex, route.Name)
```

does not work as the function `MatchString` requires only 1 argument.

I tried something like

```
myRegex , err := regexp.Compile("%s", nameRegex)
myRegex.MatchString(route.Name)
```

that too does not work.

Is it even possible to use a variable to match a regex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st parameter to MatchString is a string.  So use Sprintf (as you did earlier) to generate the pattern string, something like this:

```
regexp.MatchString(fmt.Sprintf("^%s-.*", nameRegex), route.Name)
```

or construct the string using concatentation:

```
regexp.MatchString("^" + nameRegex + "-.*", route.Name)
```

This seems to be a one-off check, so there is not need to pre-compile the regex.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Here is go playground : https://play.golang.org/p/hc9eMcSzGQC